# Selenium commands to test web applications

Tags: selenium

I have been looking to create a Selenium test using the Selenium commands below:

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html

I am aware that there is currently a Selenium IDE on Firefox which can help me with this  however this IDE does not support Google Chrome.

I am trying to create Selenium script to test a Web Application.

Here is an example of what I am trying achieve.

Suppose I was trying to locate the  element via a DOM locator which has the  ml-bind attribute

see below:

```
click(dom=document.querySelector('[ml-bind="[events]:modulesBtn"]'))
```

How would I go about writing something like this using Selenium commands?

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is an example below:

```
 // Step - 1
 // Log in to SSO & CC
 open("some website")
 type("//*[@id='email']", "")
 type("//*[@id='password']", "")

// Step - 2
clickAndWait("//*[@name='login']")

// Step - 3
open("")
assertTitle("Content Creator")

// Step - 4
// Confirm correct title is present
// Create new article
// Create a new article
clickAndWait("//*[@id='new-article-button']")
type("//*[@id='editor-inspector']/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/div[1]/textarea", "Catchpoint Synthetic Test")
type("//*[@id='editor-inspector']/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/textarea", "Catchpoint Page Title")
type("//*[@id='editor-inspector']/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[6]/div[1]/textarea", "Catchpoint short social headline")
type("//*[@id='editor-inspector']/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[7]/div[1]/textarea", "Catchpoint test preview text")
type("//*[@id='editor-inspector']/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/input", "Test User")
keyPress("//*[@id='editor-inspector']/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/input", "\13")
select("//*[@id='editor-inspector']/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/span/select", "Test")
assertSelectedLabel("//*[@id='editor-inspector']/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/span/select", "Test")
type("//*[@id='editor-inspector']/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/textarea", "This is a test article, part of a suite of synthetic user tests.  Safe to remove or disable.")

// Step - 5
// Fill in meta data
// Headline
// Enter a page title
// Enter a short social headline
// Preview text
// Add author
// Add test channel
// add some notes
// Save article
clickAndWait("//*[@id='editor-panes']/div[3]/div/div[2]/span[1]/a")
// Check that article Id was set
verifyElementPresent("//*[@id='test-articleid']")
verifyText("//*[@id='test-articleid']", "regexp:*.[0-9]{1")
click("//*[@id='tabbar']/nav/div[3]")

// Step - 6
// Log out
// CC log out
clickAndWait("//*[@id=\"tabbar\"]/nav/div[3]/ul/li/ul/li[5]/a[3]")
// SSO log out

// Step - 7
clickAndWait("link=regexp:click here")
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to test a webapp in Chrome using Selenium. You can not use Selenium IDE as this is tied to FireFox. That means you need another way of launching Selenium. If that is your question: selenium is avialable for many different environments. I use it from c# visual studio projects. Cucumber is popular, I believe that uses Java. You should look at the programming language you know, and check the tools available for that.

Comment: have you looked into selenium webdriver?

Comment: Please check my updated question above i added an example of the type of Selenium script i am writing. i am not looking to use Selenium along side another language but rather as its own language.

Comment: The code example you mentioned in your question --- which tool have you used to record that?